# soaplib with mod_wsgi/cherrypy

Tags: python, soap, mod-wsgi, cherrypy

I've followed the tutorials for setting up Apache with mod_wsgi to interface cherrypy and make a site running of it. This is my "myapp.wsgi", and opening http://localhost/ works great. Opening http://localhost/ape/ actually returns the text instead of a soap-response, and http://localhost/ape/service.wsdl returns a 500 HTTP error code. What am I doing wrong in getting such a simple SOAP service to run? How can I get it to return valid WSDL? My code follows below

Cheers

Nik

```
import atexit, threading, cherrypy,sys
from soaplib.wsgi_soap import SimpleWSGISoapApp
from soaplib.service import soapmethod
from soaplib.serializers.primitive import String, Integer, Array

sys.stdout = sys.stderr
cherrypy.config.update({'environment': 'embedded'})

class Root(object):
    def index(self):
        return 'Hello World!'
    index.exposed = True

    @soapmethod(_returns=String)
    def ape(self):
       return 'Ape!!'
    ape.exposed = True

application = cherrypy.Application(Root(), None)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just tested this myself by replacing the last line of your file with

```
cherrypy.quickstart(Root(), "/")
```

and it worked just fine for me.  I suggest trying this and seeing whether it works for you; if it does then you'll know that it's an issue relating to running it under Apache/mod_wsgi and not an inherent problem with your code.

Comment: Hi Eli, thank you very much for your time. Were you able to retrieve /ape/service.wsdl?

Answer (score 1):

Eli is right; it's not enough to just make an Application instance. You have to mount it on cherrypy.tree, which quickstart() does for you.